# Read multiple files in directory for editing and writing into another set of files

Tags: c++

I am newbie in C++ and appreciate if someone could help me figure this out. I wrote the following code and it works fine but I need to repeat it for many files in the same directory. It reads 0.txt line by line, removes lines of strings of characters if found and writes the rest of the lines which are only numbers into another file named 0.dat. I need to repeat this for multiple files (0.txt,1.txt....100.txt) in the same directory.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <string>
    int main()
    {
    std::ifstream in;
    std::ofstream out;
    in.open("0.txt");
    out.open("0.dat");
    if(in.is_open() && out.is_open()){
         while(std::getline(in, line)){
                if(line.find(" No.")==line.npos){
                         out << line << "\n";
                         std::cout << "line is:\t" << line<<"\n";
                }
          }
    }

    in.close();
    out.close();
    return 0;
    }
```

How can I create a loop to read 100 "*.txt" files and write them into 100 "*.dat" files with correct name reference?

Comment: If you are performing no operations on the data before writing to the dat file you may be able to take advantage of  `std::filesystem::copy` to copy the file.

Comment: Does the loop need to be within your program?  You might find it easier to use a shell script for the glue: `for f in *.txt; do your_program <"$f" >"${f%.txt}.dat"; done`, for example.

Comment: @Toby Speight, No, it does not have to. I got it worked from below answer but writing a shell will also be a convenient way. I am just curious how will it work. Should I do: for f in *.txt; mycode.c <"$f" >"${f%.txt}.dat"; done in a shell script?

Comment: For the loop to work like that, your program will need to cooperate a bit - make it a pipeline, so that it reads from standard input and writes to standard output, instead of opening files itself; then something like that shell loop will meet your needs.  (And you should invoke your *compiled program* within the loop, not the C++ source!)

Answer (score 2):

It's simple, really. First thing we will do is make that stuff you've already written into a function. But not before making some edits. It should do exactly the same thing your code does, but with better practices!

```
void readAndWrite(std::string in_name, std::string out_name)
{
    std::ifstream in{in_name};
    std::ofstream out{out_name};
    std::string line;

    if (!in.is_open() || !out.is_open())
        return;

    while (std::getline(in, line)) {
        if (line.find(" No.") == line.npos) {
            out << line << "\n";
            std::cout << "line is:\t" << line<<"\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Then we just need to call it 100 times with our file names. I'll assume that your files are named like "0.txt", "1.txt", ... and so on. We can do this using `std::to_string()`, a function which, as the name implies, changes things to `std::string`s. In our case, we'll be changing `int`s to `std::string`s. This is one way to do it. (this will be in `main`):

```
#include <string>
...
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    std::string fname = std::to_string(i);
    readAndWrite(fname + ".txt", fname + ".dat");
}
```

And that should do it!